# Unique file identifier in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to know whether there's any unique id with which we can distinguish files in ***Dropbox***. Because when we copy/move a file in dropbox,it is detected as a new change by ***delta api***. And it would be good if we can distinguish files in dropbox with a unique id. I've done some research and didn't find anything. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Dropbox API v2 does now offer file IDs that persist across moves/renames. You can find more information under "Path formats" in [the documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats).

The file ID is available as the `id` field on the `FileMetadata` object, e.g., as returned by [/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata).

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for :)